# How to rephrase this sentence in order to be more American style?

Tags: american-english

I want to rephrase this sentence:

> A challenge that it needs to address is how to best
>       perform feature selection.

If the sentence looks like this, how to rephrase it:

> A challenge that it needs to address is how to best
>       perform feature selection in order to ...

it refers to a new method. Can anyone give me a help?

Comment: What style do you profess this sentence is? Just to be clear...

Comment: It sounds American enough already to my ear! If you want it in better English, I'd suggest: *One challenge it faces is in how best to perform feature selection*.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. **Proofreading questions ("Is this right?", "Are there any mistakes?")** or **Writing advice (see [Writers.SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com/) instead) or critique requests are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified**. Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @WS2, your suggestion seems more formal for written english.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy, I want it to be more formal in written english.

Comment: @WS2, I modified the question.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy, I modified the question. Please take a look at it!

Comment: This is only borderline on-topic. It would be improved if you could add **why you feel the second sentence is substandard** at the moment. It's complex, certainly; but then it's expressing a complex idea. You will probably end up having to rephrase the whole thing, but there are almost as many versions possible as there are members here (that is, it's too broad).

Comment: The feature selection process needs improving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a more conventional word order and get rid of the passive "is". "It needs to address the challenge of how to best perform feature selection..."

Comment: you mean I can write is like this: It needs to address the challenge of how to best perform feature selection in order to...

Comment: Yes. You certainly can.

Comment: Can I rephrase like this:" One challenge it faces is in how best to perform feature selection in order to... ". Or I should remove "in" here, and rephrase it as: " One challenge it faces is how best to perform feature selection in order to"?

Comment: I find the extra words annoying and feel they make the sentence seem clumsy.

Comment: you mean it is right to rephrase in this way:  " One challenge it faces is how best to perform feature selection in order to...  ". Am I right?

Comment: It's right in the sense that it is not a grammatical error, but it is clumsy and unpleasant to listen to. The extra words just get annoying.

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the fluff.  Get to the point.

> Feature selection needs to be addressed.

An economical and understated style popularized by American author Ernest Hemingway.